Showing $f \in W^{1,p}(\Bbb{R}^2)$ for $p \in [1,2)$ but $f$ is not continuous.
Fix $\psi \in C_c^\infty(\Bbb{R}^2)$ such that $\psi \vert_B \equiv 1$ where $B$ is the unit ball in $\Bbb{R}^2$. Define $f \in C_c^\infty(\Bbb{R}^2)$ by
$$f(x_1,x_2)=\psi(x_1,x_2)\frac{x_1^2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}.$$
Prove $f \in W^{1,p}(\Bbb{R}^2)$ for $p \in [1,2)$ but $f$ is not continuous.
So is the function discontinuous because at the origin its not continuous? Also I dont see why it $p \geq 2$ this doesnt work?'
So I need to show $f \in L^p$ and $D^j f \in L^p$ for any multi index $j$ with $\vert j \vert \leq 1$?
As per the posed answer, if $f_\epsilon(x)=\psi(x)\frac{x^2}{x^2+\epsilon^2}$ then
$$f_\epsilon'(x)=\psi'(x)\frac{x^2}{x^2+\epsilon^2}+\psi(x)\frac{2x\epsilon^2}{(x^2+\epsilon^2)^2}$$
which tends to $\psi'(x)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$?
Can someone please help me I am very stuck! The answer didn’t help me much!

When $p>2$ we have Sobolev embedding $W^{1,p}(\Bbb R^2)\hookrightarrow C^0(\Bbb R^2)$. This would break down when $p=2$ if you consider the function $g(x)=\psi(x)\log\sqrt{|\log|x||}$.
Back to your question, $f(0,t)\equiv 0$ but $f(t,0)\equiv 1$ when $t\to0$, so $f$ is not continuous.
You can compute $\partial_jf$ by checking its value when $x\neq0$ first. If you want a rigorous proof, use $f_\epsilon(x)=\psi(x)\frac{x_1^2}{x^2+\epsilon^2}$ and proceed a limit argument similar to what I've done recently this this answer.

should there be a subscript in your definition of $f_\epsilon(x)$ in the numerator?

@homosapien You can, but it's not necessary. Here $f_\epsilon$ is already smooth.

also, is my only possibility for $j$ just $j=1$ here?

@homosapien I assuming you can talk about $j=2,3,4,\dots$ in general. Yes here $|j|\le1$ means $j=0,1$.

Also, for showing $Df \in L^p$ do I need the product rule for weak derivatives? as $f$ is the product of two functions?

Do the derivative for $f_\epsilon$ first, and then take the limit. You can use whatever you learned in calculus first.

I did this and I get $\psi'(x)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.. am I on the right track?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
